# How to make a automatic splice in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

**Hi, everyone**

I need little bit help related to creating Coupon function. Let me explain my idea, for example I have 5 coupons and I want to give each one to only one customer. And I also want that when one Coupon is loaded next time it doesn't load.

I know how to create arrays:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Testing Coucpon</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function coupon() {
   //CreatingArrays
   amazoncoupon = new Array (4);

   //Initializing Arrays
   amazoncoupon [0] = "sale2017";
   amazoncoupon [1] = "Guest";
   amazoncoupon [2] = "Welcome";
   amazoncoupon [3] = "Happy";

   return amazoncoupon.splice (0,1);
  }
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <center>
 <h1> Hi </h1>
 <script>
 coupon();
 </script>

 </center>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But I want a to complete it, like want to splice each element in array everytime when this script loads.

So first time coupon "Sale2017" will load and will be displayed to customer but it is deleted also. So next time when page loads there should be next coupon  which is "Guest".

Let say Coupon is "sale2017", so when buyer put his email address on first page to get coupon, upon submission he will be redirected to second page where javascript function starts and Coupon loads on second page and shows to customer, but I also want that this coupon never ever load again when next time other customer submit email.

Can you please provide me idea and code to complete this.

Comment: You can't trust the client with this. You need to user server side code.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it on the client, because the client doesn't know anything about other clients, right?

But you can do it on the server easily, of course you need some kind of stateful datastore, to know which coupons were used, which not.

Comment: No basically coupons are stored on Amazon. We will put list on JS. Then if customer will get coupon and also buy from amazon that coupon will be removed. But if buyer get coupon but he don't buy product from amazon then coupon will be still available on amazon. So we will again update it and add it in our array.

Comment: So, whats your problem?

Comment: I don;t know which function to use which delete elements in array on every loading of page.

Comment: 'Array.splice/filter / delete array[index]'

Comment: Can you check above I created, but its not working.

Comment: You don't understand that your idea cannot work without server side logic, thats all. All your tryings are just waste of time. Because you expect, that client A gets "coupon 1" and client B gets "coupon 2", for this you have to generate another html file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
function generateToken() {
  return amazoncoupon.splice(0,1);
}
```

Every time, you need to pop the first element and display it to the user.

Comment: What is mean by splice(0); can you explain this. As I am new to JS.

Comment: Splice(0,1) deletes the 1st element from an array and returns it.

Comment: Can you create little script for DEMO. Like create arrays and put this function.

Comment: Please check in question I created a script through you method but its not working.

Comment: You are re-initializing array every time. You should initialize the array only one time so that each time `coupon()` is called, the 1st element will be deleted from the array and returned to the user.